# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, json

I am new to working with JSON in C# using Newtonsoft JSON.Net and having a problem deserializing the following response.  Here's the first part of it.

```
"response":{
    "sxt_func_ack":
        {"sxt_func_ack":
            [
                {"coNo":1,"correlation_data":"","data1":"11036990-00","errorNo":0 ...}
            ]
        },
```

Here's the beginning of the class

```
public class response_cls : Response
{
    public response_cls()
    {
        sxapi_oehdr = new Generic.List<sxapi_oehdr_cls>();
        sxapi_oeitm = new Generic.List<sxapi_oeitm_cls>();
        sxt_func_ack = new Generic.List<sxt_func_ack_cls>();
    }

    public Generic.List<sxt_func_ack_cls> sxt_func_ack { get; set; }
    public Generic.List<sxapi_oehdr_cls> sxapi_oehdr { get; set; }
    public Generic.List<sxapi_oeitm_cls> sxapi_oeitm { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to do to the class to be able to deserialize this data?

Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON has two levels of "sxt_func_ack" while your object model only has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets in your json mean that the property is a collection. It's a little unclear from your extract but I can think of two schemas that fit the sample you provided. Both successfully deserialize using the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("json1.json");
        Body body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Body>(json);
    }
}
```

In the first, the two `sxt_func_ack` properties are different types:

```
public class Body
{
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public Class1 Sxt_func_ack { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public IEnumerable<Class2> Sxt_func_ack { get; set; }

}

public class Class2
{
    public int CoNo { get; set; }
    public string Correlation_data { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public int ErrorNo { get; set; }
}
```

In the second, both `sxt_func_ack` properties are the same type:

```
public class Body
{
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public Class1 Sxt_func_ack { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public IEnumerable<Class1> Sxt_func_ack { get; set; }
    public int CoNo { get; set; }
    public string Correlation_data { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public int ErrorNo { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Ahhh!  @Ben Not really understanding JSON I thought the two sxt_func_ack were somehow connected at the same level.

Comment: Using your second suggestion I was able to get it to work.  Thanks to both of you!

Comment: You are welcome @SteveHanna. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.